# Flask-bootstrap simple app not rendering bootstrap correctly

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm having some problems to get a simple flask app to use the flask-bootstrap package.

Following the documentation I installed flask-bootstrap, created the 2 files below and this worked fine. The problem I'm facing is that when I access index.html in the browser I see only the text *bootstrap/base.html* returned and see no reference to the bootstrap css files when I view the source.

Appreciate any guidance on what I am missing here.
Thanks.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap 

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}This is an example page{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Hello, Bootstrap</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you running your flask APP ??? Plus to see the effect, you should run your app from a browser by typing for example `localhost:5000`, depending on that you configure your flask app

Comment: Thanks for response. I have the app on a server and access the domain via the browser. So should be running ok. Without the extends bootstrap the app runs ok.

Comment: I'm very confused here , you said *"created the 2 files below and this worked fine"* and then you said *"when I access index.html"*, so how did it work for u in the first place and how are u accessing `index.html`?, shouldn't `index.html` be the root page just by typing in the browser `localhost:5000` for example?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the installation of flask bootstrap was fine and the upload of the files to the server was successful. When i say access index.html i mean i goto www.mydomain.com/

Comment: Are u using some sort of Virtual Env?

Comment: Yeah. I installed flask and flask bootstrap on a virtual env.

Comment: I believe, to extract the issue here, you should run your flask app on your Virtual Env. on your own computer, test it then if everything is fine, (http://localhost:5000), then if all good, you can upload it to your server, this is how I would do it,

Comment: try `from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap` per @IronFist you'll get more verbose debug & stacktrace info running on your local machine in the development server

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I've not set up a local dev environment on my computer so think im trying to run before i can walk here.

Comment: @Terryb, don't forget to enable debug mode in your dev. environment, and come back with your findings, :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the hints regarding the setup and proper use of virtualenv.

After some further digging I discovered that I should have the following 2 lines added to the top of **flaskapp.wsgi** since I installed bootstrap on the virtual environment created for my app, namely **venv**

```
activate_this = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```